# Delete files that are encrypted and sent

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I have this email program where I encrypt the data (attachments and body of the message) and send it over the net.

I have a `encryptcheckbox`, when checked AND `sendbutton` is click, the attachments are message are encrypted and sent to the recipients.

I uses the didisoft pgp .dll files to have the reference of encryption and decryption algorithm.

```
using System.IO;
using DidiSoft.Pgp;

class EncryptDemo {
 public void Demo() {
     // create an instance of the library
     PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

     // specify should the output be ASCII or binary
     bool asciiArmor = false;
     // should additional integrity information be added
     // set to false for compatibility with older versions of PGP such as 6.5.8.
     bool withIntegrityCheck = false;

     pgp.EncryptFile(@"C:\Test\INPUT.txt",
                     @"C:\Test\public_key.asc",
                     @"C:\Test\OUTPUT.pgp",
                     asciiArmor,
                     withIntegrityCheck);
 }
}
```

The part @"C:\Test\OUTPUT.pgp", it actually creates the encrypted file attachment in my computer (why would you want a encrypted file?). So, my intention was to let it create, but delete it after `sendbutton` is clicked (in other words, after my mail is sent).

Comment: Like @jester said, File.Delete will do the job, but why are you surprise it creates a file? what would you like it to do with the input otherwise? I guess you could save it to memory or into a stream, but the simple way would be just to delete it once you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it using the `File` class in `System.IO` once your `send` action is complete:

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\Test\OUTPUT.pgp"))
{
    File.Delete(@"C:\Test\OUTPUT.pgp");
}
```